# How to override a global boolean value within a function

Tags: python

```
from playsound import playsound
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

def play_song(song_index, loc, song_list):
    global play
    while play:
        try:
            playsound(fr'{loc}\{song_list[song_index]}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error: {e}')
            break

def controls(input):
    global play
    if input == 'stop':
        play = False
        print('stopped')

play = True
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        user = input('Enter folder name [Desktop]:\n>> ')
        loc = fr'{os.environ["USERPROFILE"]}\Desktop\{user}'
        music_dict = {name: index for name, index in enumerate(os.listdir(loc))}

        for index in music_dict:
            print(f'{index}) {music_dict[index]}')
        
        choice = int(input(f'Play song[1-{index}]:\n>> '))
        
        p1 = Process(target=play_song, args=(choice, loc, music_dict))
        p1.start()

        control = str(input('>> ')).lower()

        p2 = Process(target=controls, args=(control,))
        p2.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()
```

When the user inputs 'stop' I want to make `play = False` to stop the music and repeat the `while True` loop, I tried using the `global` keyword but for some reason it is not working.

Comment: Unrelated, but `{name: index for name, index in enumerate(os.listdir(loc))}` looks like you've got the names and indices backward.

Comment: Also, processes don't share globals.

Comment: You are using two different processes, **processes do not share state**.

Comment: Each process runs in its own memory-space, so generally speaking there can't be global variables shared between them. However in Python 3.8 a [`multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory) class was added, so maybe you can use that.

Comment: There's no way to stop a sound being played by the `playsound` module, so regardless of anything else, simply setting a flag will never work. You'll need to use a better audio module in order to do what you want. I think there's one is `pygame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problem here is that you are using `multiprocessing`: Workers in a different process do not share global variables with the parent process: it will "see" another instance of the "play" variable.

This is the major difference between multiprocessing and multithreading: in multithreading, global variables are unique, and changes in one thread are visible in other threads. This comes with its own set of problems, but fr simple cases like this, it would just work:

Replace `multiprocessing.Process` there with `threading.Thread` and it would work. Note however that your worker thread will check the variable only when the song is over and it would skip to the next one (or rather, the way your code is, when it would start-over the same song).

If you want to really fix it, check the use of `Queue` classes (there are both multithreading, async,  and multiprocessing versions) and use those to control your worker, including sending the path for the next songs to be played.

Also, if you want to stop a song midway, which looks reasonable, you should stick with multiprocessing: then you stop the process by sending a kill signal to it - it is not possible to stop a thread in the same way: once Python would relinquish the control to the
`playsound` call, you'd hav to wait for it to finnish. (But I suspect the playsound library have finer grained controls, in other calls than `playsound.playsound` so that a song can be paused/resumed/stopped short of terminating the process - OH My!, googling for the docs, it actually does not have any controls - so the remote kill would work)